# Printing a duplex color print in WPF- c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a weird problem and couldn't manage to get my head around it.
I've one desktop application built using WPF C#. It only prints the pdf files but due to some reason there's a problem while printing a duplex color print. all other prints are fine (single side, black duplex)

The code to print is:

```
var printFilePath = "\"" + docFileName + "\"";
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                Verb = "print",
                FileName = printFilePath,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            };

            var p = new Process {StartInfo = info};
            p.Start();

            p.WaitForInputIdle();

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
            {
                if (p.WaitForExit(2000) == false)
                {
                    p.Kill();
                }
            }
```

One more thing for setting the default print I'm using `winspool.drv`

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
```

So can someone guide me, what could be the possible problem?